# Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Please, help me. I have a variable lang and i know that after this variable must go characters `-(.+);`
For example, i would have written it in C # so - `regexString = lang + "-(.+);";`
But in javascript this code not correct: `str1 = str1.replace(lang+"-(.+);", replacement);` because there must use /.../, but i don't know how to write correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dynamic way to create regexps in javascript:

```
new RegExp(lang+'\-(.+)')
```

(I also escaped the `-`.)

So to do a replace:

```
str.replace(new Regexp(lang+'\-(.+)'), replacement)
```

If you want to replace more than 1:

```
str.replace(new Regexp(lang+'\-(.+)', 'g'), replacement)
```

The `'g'` flag is for 'global'.

Comment: Why would you escape `-` outside a character class?

Comment: Because if you always escape the `-`, you never forget to. That's how I was taught =)

Comment: good point.  That's how I like to do it as well -- never want to accidentally forget to escape a dash or another symbol and spend the next few days pulling out hair.

Comment: this is my code:
`var reg = new RegExp(lang + "-(.+);");
text = text.replace(reg, "");`
debugger return error Unexpected quantifier on first code line

Answer (score 0):

Use `new RegExp(lang + '-(.+);')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var re = new RegExp(lang+"-(.+);");
str1 = str1.replace(re, replacement);
```